# How to close a channel

Tags: go, synchronization, queue

I try to adapt this example:
https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

But I don't know how to stop the channel because program don't exit at the end of the channel loop.

Can you explain how to exit the program?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/SlyMarbo/rss"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func readLines(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }
    return lines, scanner.Err()
}


func worker(id int, jobs <-chan string, results chan<- string) {
    for url := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "processing job", url)
        feed, err := rss.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error on: ", url)
            continue
        }
        borne := 0
        for _, value := range feed.Items {
            if borne < 5 {
                results <- value.Link
                borne = borne +1
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }
}


func main() {
    jobs := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan string)

    for w := 1; w <= 16; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }


    urls, err := readLines("flux.txt")
    if err != nil { 
        log.Fatalf("readLines: %s", err) 
    }

    for _, url := range urls {
        jobs <- url
    }

    close(jobs)

    // it seems program runs over...
    for msg := range results {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

The flux.txt is a flat text file like :

- http://blog.case.edu/news/feed.atom
- ...

Comment: You need to close the `results` chan when all your workers are done. Are you asking *how* to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, in the example you are referring to, the worker pool reads from `results` 9 times:

```
for a := 1; a <= 9; a++ {
    <-results
}
```

Your program, on the other hand, does a range loop over the `results` which has a different semantics in go. The range operator does not stop until the channel is closed.

```
for msg := range results {
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

To fix your problem you'd need to close the `results` channel. However, if you just call `close(results)` before the for loop, you most probably will 
get a panic, because the workers might be writing on `results`.

To fix this problem, you need to add another channel to be notified when all the workers are done. You can do this either using a `sync.WaitGroup` or :

```
const (
    workers = 16
)

func main() {
    jobs := make(chan string, 100)
    results := make(chan string, 100)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
        go func() {
            wg.Add(1)
            defer wg.Done()
            worker(w, jobs, results)
        }()
    }

    urls, err := readLines("flux.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("readLines: %s", err)
    }

    for _, url := range urls {
        jobs <- url
    }

    close(jobs)

    wg.Wait()

    close(results)

    // it seems program runs over...
    for msg := range results {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

Or a `done` channel:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/SlyMarbo/rss"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func readLines(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }
    return lines, scanner.Err()
}

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan string, results chan<- string, done chan struct{}) {
    for url := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "processing job", url)
        feed, err := rss.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error on: ", url)
            continue
        }
        borne := 0
        for _, value := range feed.Items {
            if borne < 5 {
                results <- value.Link
                borne = borne + 1
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }
    close(done)
}

const (
    workers = 16
)

func main() {
    jobs := make(chan string, 100)
    results := make(chan string, 100)
    dones := make([]chan struct{}, workers)

    for w := 0; w < workers; w++ {
        dones[w] = make(chan struct{})
        go worker(w, jobs, results, dones[w])
    }

    urls, err := readLines("flux.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("readLines: %s", err)
    }

    for _, url := range urls {
        jobs <- url
    }


    close(jobs)

    for _, done := range dones {
        <-done
    }

    close(results)

    // it seems program runs over...
    for msg := range results {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example is essentially making a less efficient WaitGroup, that's harder to get right.

Comment: Right, but I am just trying to enumerate the options here. I have no idea about the actual program and in some cases the channel-based alternative works best.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I understand better now the operation.

Nonetheless, I tested two solutions, but none solves the problem.

In 2 cases, goroutines embark but there is no result returned, the print is ineffective and I did not see the tail will unstack results.

I do not understand why with your solutions, this does not solve the problem.

I am new golang but I'm used to working with the queues, threads and coroutines in Python.

But, I do not understand why this is not working.

Comment: If you want test, the flux.txt file is a flat text file with rss/atom.